# AWS Lambda Node runtime update from Node.js v4.3 to Node.js v8.10

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We created a function in **AWS Lambda** using **Node v4.3**.  Later we upgraded the function to **Node v8.10**. When I just update the runtime of the function, it updates the runtime fine and I can execute the code just fine without errors.

It that all needed to upgrade from **Node.js v4.3** to **Node.js v8.10**?

I used the following command:

`aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name functionname --runtime nodejs8.10`

Is this a clean way to perform an upgrade of the runtime version of Node.js in Lambda or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, normally that is all that is needed.  The key is testing to ensure nothing breaks.  You can also verify via the GUI that the function is using the new runtime.

Comment: I will keep posted if I see any trouble.